# Variable set in jest is unavailable outside tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

While wanting to test if setting a variable works well, I realize how jest was working. I understand this behavior, but, I need to be able to test if setting my variable works, and then, prepare some tests from outside the test, using this variable. Is there a way to do so? Or can't I test if setting the variable works well, if I need to use it to set the next tests?

This code :

```js
var value = 0;
console.log("Before test " + value);
test("set value ", () => {
  expect(() => {
    value = 1;
    console.log("Set " + value);
  }).not.toThrowError();
});
test("get value ", () => {
  expect(() => {
    console.log("Get " + value);
  }).not.toThrowError();
});

console.log("After test " + value);
const valueForOtherTest = value + 1;

test("Do others tests... ", () => {
  expect(() => {
    console.log("Doing some stuff with ... " + valueForOtherTest);
  }).not.toThrowError();
});
```

Produces this output :

```
 PASS  tests/fake.test.js  
  ● Console

    console.log
      Before test 0

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/fake.test.js:2:9)

    console.log
      After test 0

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/fake.test.js:15:9)

    console.log
      Set 1

      at tests/fake.test.js:6:13

    console.log
      Get 1

      at tests/fake.test.js:11:13

    console.log
      Doing some stuff with ... 1

      at tests/fake.test.js:20:13
```

I would need to find a way so

```
      After test 0
```

would be

```
      After test 1
```

So then, in do other stuff... I could do whatever I need from the operation made half in test/half outside of test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [setup & tear down functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#one-time-setup) for jest. The `afterAll` function will run after all the tests have completed.

But that is not really the way to 'test' this.
If you want to test it, you should write an assertion.

```
describe('tests', () => {
    let value = 0;

    beforeAll(() => {
        value = 1;
        console.log('setting value to 1', value);
    });

    test('test-1', () => {
        console.log('value in test-1', value);
        expect(value).toEqual(1);
    });

    describe('tests - 2', () => {
        beforeAll(() => {
            value = 2;
            console.log('setting value to 2', value);
        });

        test('test-2', () => {
            console.log('value in test-2', value);
            expect(value).toEqual(2);
        });
    });
});
```

If you need to run other code - you could also call that other code from the test and await it (if it is async) and then just proceed with the tests in a far less complex manner. i.e. making the state changes in the tests themselves.

```
    describe('tests', () => {
    let value = 0;

    test('test - 1', () => {
        // set state here
        value = 1;
        expect(value).toEqual(1);
    });

    test('test - 2', () => {
        // get Value
        expect(value).toEqual(1);
    });

    test('test-3', async () => {
        // run the other code
        // if it is async await it
        // await changeToObject()
        expect(value).toBe('some-other-value');
    });

    test('test-4', () => {
        expect(value).toBe('some-other-value');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sadly, it would not work for me. This example is really simplified. Maybe  it is not clear enough. I have a random segfault that happen when I create an object, so, I want to check when that happen. So I need to test if something happen during the creation of this object (here simplified by value = 1), but after that, I need to get other values from this newly created object, to prepares other tests. And I can't do this preparation from inside a test (the tests are inside a loop, that use info from the object, so I would have to do a test in a test, which is not supported as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe I should update my post to show a less simplified example ?

Comment: Possible to trouble shoot that using a debugger?

Comment: It doesn't look like a bug. The tests are runs after all code outside of tests have been run, but, I need to do some tests, then run some code outside of test, then do some others tests. Or maybe there is something I don't know about ?

Comment: I update my post in hopes that it would be clearer

Comment: Have added an update - It may not be the best way to approach this - maybe a debugger would be better. Write a test to make all the state changes you require and step through them in a debugger would be best. However, that being said, I still think that you can achieve what you want with setup and tear down functions. It is also worth noting that you could always make the state change in the test rather than the setups. I would also have a read of the order of execution of tests that are written in describe blocks to make sure that there are no surprises :).

Comment: @Elley From what you described, before/afterEach probably suits your case better.

Comment: I realised that I may not have approached my issue on the right angle on this post, beforeAll seem correct in this situation, but my problem is finally slighty different, so I made a new post. But thank you both !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank to you, I think I have found what I needed to resolve this situation, the answer I came with is :

```js
var value = 0;
console.log("Before test " + value);
test("set value ", () => {
  expect(() => {
    value = 1;
    console.log("Set " + value);
  }).not.toThrowError();
});
test("get value ", () => {
  expect(() => {
    console.log("Get " + value);
  }).not.toThrowError();
});
var valueForOtherTest;
describe("matching cities to foods", () => {
  // Applies only to tests in this describe block

  beforeAll(() => {
    console.log("After test " + value);
    valueForOtherTest = value + 1;
  });
  test("get value ", () => {
    expect(() => {
      console.log("Doing some stuff with ... " + valueForOtherTest);
    }).not.toThrowError();
  });
});
```

And gives me this outputs :

```
 PASS  tests/fake.test.js      
  ● Console

    console.log
      Before test 0

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/fake.test.js:2:9)

    console.log
      Set 1

      at tests/fake.test.js:6:13

    console.log
      Get 1

      at tests/fake.test.js:11:13

    console.log
      After test 1

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/fake.test.js:19:13)

    console.log
      Doing some stuff with ... 2

      at tests/fake.test.js:24:15`
```

Since you weren't adding value to valueForOtherTest in your code example, I thought that I could still not access value when I needed like that. Reading the doc helped me. So, thank you for your help !

Sadly, it still partially respond to my need. But, I think that I focused my issue on the wrong angle from the beginning. I will open a new post to explore this new angle.